# Linux. PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

Установил PostgreSQL на Linux. Проблема в том, что я не могу пользоваться командой **psql**, т.к. требует пароль. При установке вроде пароль не требовался. Пробовал вводить пароль от сервера, не срабатывало.
Пытался удалить PostgreSQL с сервера, не получилось, т.к. требует пароль.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: При установке PostgreSQL создает учетную запись postgres. Зайдите под нее из рута и уже оттуда входите в psql: `su - postgres` (ну или сразу `sudo -u postgres psql`).

Comment: Проблема осталась та же. Могу ли я удалить PostgreSQL? При удалении требует пароль.

Comment: Вообще не должно быть такого, он может требовать только пароль от root или текущего пользователя, но никак не пароль postgres. Может он все-таки требует ваш пароль?

Comment: Что значит "проблема осталась та же"? Какую ошибку пишет su/sudo?

Comment: Насчет проблемы, я имел ввиду ошибку `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Какой дистрибутив Linux? Как устанавливали PostgeSQL?

Answer (score 3):

1. в файле `pg_hba.conf` поменять метод-аутентификации на `trust`
2. перезапустить сервис PostgreSQL
3. запустить `psql` и выполнить `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newpass';`
4. вернуть прежний метод-аутентификации в файле `pg_hba.conf`
5. снова перезапустить сервис PostgreSQL

Comment: Сделал, как вы написали. Теперь команду psql вызвать могу (пароль не требует). Но при вызове `sudo systemctl start postgresql` требует пароль от postgres. Перезапустить тоже не могу, т.к. требует пароль.

Comment: Всё-таки спрашивает пароль у вас  текущего залогиненного пользователя, с правами на запуск sudo, а не пароль от postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта:

1. Залогиниться под "Администратором":

   `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

   Попросит пароль от текущего пользователя.
2. Создать нового пользователя и базу:

   ```
   sudo -u postgres createuser -l имя
   sudo -u postgres cratedb -O имя имя_новой_базы
   psql имя_новой_базы
   ```

   Попросит пароль от текущего пользователя.

   `имя` - имя текущего пользователя в системе.

Если говорит, что пароль не правильный:

```
su root
```

Пароль пользователя `root` сервера.

```
su postgres
```

А дальше один из примеров выше, только без `sudo -u postgres`.